# Python: Using recursion to efficiently determine sum of factors

Tags: python, recursion

```
def sof (x, fact):
    if x % fact == 0:
        if fact >= x/fact:
            return fact + x/fact + sof (x,fact - 1)
        else:
            return 1
    else:
        return sof (x,fact-1)
```

How can I make this program more efficient runtime wise? I am personally exhausted of ideas.

Comment: Step 1 is to make it work. Right now, it doesn't. Try it with `x=4`.

Comment: Do you need to stick with recursion? This program could be done iteratively, and it will probably be more efficient that way, since Python doesn't do any tail call elimination.

Comment: Does it have to be recursive?

Comment: Sorry, I excluded some information from the opening post. X must be int(math.ceil(x/2)). The divisors added must be proper divisors. And, yes it must be recursion. I am having trouble with some numbers though.

Comment: @Blckknght: The lack of tail call elimination won't affect the algorithmic complexity; all it does is add a small constant multiplier, and of course limit it to 1000 steps.

Comment: @user3225528: What is this `X` that must be `int(math.ceil(x/2))` exactly? Where does it fit into the program?

Comment: How is the problem specified, exactly? Are you supposed to be summing the prime factors, or all pairs of factors along the way? If a number is an exact square, do you count its square root once or twice?

Comment: And how is this called? Are you supposed to call `sof(x, x)`, or pick a "guess" at the highest factor to pass in for the initial call, or pass any arbitrary number, or …?

Comment: Also, please give an example that's "too slow"—how long it takes, how long you think it should take, what your expectation of the runtime complexity is supposed to be, etc. Because from a quick glance, I'd expect anything that falls within the recursion limit to finish in microseconds…

Comment: The problem is I have to sum the proper factors of a number, I was not given a definite template for the program so I can do anything. Square roots are only counted once.

Comment: Though unspecified, I want to be able to run numbers over 4000 without exceeding my recursive limit (900)

Comment: Originally, in my program I had the two parameters because I figure the first factor of the number would be half of the number. That would eliminate runtime by half.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to be able to run numbers over 4000 without exceeding my
>   recursive limit

Here's one way to make the program more *efficient*, though not necessarily *faster*. In your code the base case of the recursion:

```
if fact >= x // fact:
```

is nested *inside* the remainder check:

```
if x % fact == 0:
```

Making it possible for your code to keep checking numbers that it doesn't need to.  (E.g. consider a large prime * 2 -- your code keeps checking until `fact` reaches 1 instead of the halfway point.)

This isn't a speed issue for the small numbers that this algorithm can handle before the stack overflows.  You only reach 1999 beyond which the stack overflows whereas my rearrangement:

```
def sof(number, divisor):
    dividend = number // divisor

    if dividend > divisor:
        return 1

    if number % divisor:
        return sof(number, divisor - 1)

    return divisor + dividend + sof(number, divisor - 1)
```

can reach 2086 with the same stack size as it avoids those extra recursions.

And that difference increases as you expand the stack via `sys.setrecursionlimit()`.